# angular geohash unexpected token export

Tags: angular, geohashing

i'm using geohash to convert lat lng to a geohash. Todo so i implemented the library geohash.js. Unfortunately angular is saying "unexpected token export, which is at the bottom of the latlon-geohash.js:

```
export default Geohash
```

here is how i implemented the lib:
angular.json:

```
    "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js",
          "./node_modules/latlon-geohash/latlon-geohash.js"
        ]
```

and my component:

```
import Geohash from 'latlon-geohash';
```